# Xcode 6.3.1 Simulator UI Errors

Tags: xcode, autolayout, simulator

Since updating to Xcode 6.3.1, my Simulator isn't rendering my UI elements consistently with autolayout.

My detailViews render the same IB layout inconsistently, with one view truncated while the other view is fine. Both are properly constrained. This only happened after installing the new update.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say "simulator", are you talking about the iOS device simulator, or the Preview Assistant?

Does this issue reproduce on device?

Can you post a screenshot showing all of your constraints for the affected view?