# Screen content is only shown in a part of screen in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, ios-simulator, xamarin.forms

My iOS Simulator only show the content as a part of the screen. How can I fix it? I'm using XCode 6.3.1. Thanks

[image]

Comment: We're not magicians, please show us your source code.

Comment: I'm not a magican too. It's just a Xamarin.Forms application and I don't have any special code. BTW, I create a empty Single page application in XCode and it has the same problem.

Comment: add 'xamarin' tag to your question for more help from xamarin coders.

Comment: Is the issue just with your app?  If you hit shift-cmd-h, does the home screen look correct, or is it shoved up in the upper left corner?  If you take a screenshot from the File menu, does it look correct (it is saved to desktop)?  How reproducible is this?  Does changing the zoom in the window menu fix it?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia The home screen also appears on a part of screen. Taking screenshot has same result. And it happens every times.Changing zoom cannot fix it. It must be a bug of the simulator.

Comment: Actually, what you describe makes me think it's not a bug of the simulator but of the runtime.  Please file a radar and attach the screenshot showing the home screen rather than your app exhibiting the problem as well as a tarball of ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator

Comment: Seem it's a Xamarin's bug. After upgrading to latest alpha version of Xamarin, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to restart it. It can happen sometimes.
Force close simulator and start it again!

Comment: @AgileHobo I think what he meant is close the simulator first then run it again. If it still didn't work, try changing the device simulator after you close the simulator, then run it again.

Answer (score 1):

I am including this response for those, who like me, are seeking an solution for this problem after upgrading to Xcode 8.

The simulator began using only a portion of the display, as described in the question, when testing against iOS 8.x. The symptoms were that 1/4 of the display was showing if the window scale was set to 50%, 1/9 would show if the scale was set to 33%, etc. The entire display would show only if the scale was set to 100%, which is a real pain when using an iPad simulator.

The solution for me was to turn off "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale" under the "Debug" menu, which first seems to have appeared in Xcode 8. The 8.x simulators displayed properly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image..

I think it has something to do with the resolution/scale of the simulator.. I dont use Xcode 6.3.1 though...
since it's 5s the screen resolution/scale is x2.. so instead of 320x568 it must be 640x1136..

why dont you use the device frame rect to fill the screen? something like `self.view.frame` ?

its hard to guess what causing your problem,show us something that may help.. :)

Comment: I have almost zero experience with iOS development. It's a Xamarin.Forms application. BTW, I create a empty Single page application in XCode and it has the same problem.

Comment: I'm a full time ios dev. as of this moment so, i not that familiar with xamarin.forms yet.. 
but since it support multi platfroms, what you really want to do is check the  device your application is running, then check the resolution then rescale your views based from that.. 

you can also check this out **Craig Dunn** as answer they have some discussion about that.. [https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19917/ios-app-not-displaying-in-full-screen]

Comment: As I created a empty Single page application in XCode and it had the same problem so it should be a bug of iOS Simulator. I don't have this problem with XCode 6.3

Comment: Okay, about that.. it seems you're not the only one..
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837802/xcode-6-3-1-simulator-ui-errors) Actually i, personally dont like Xcode 6.x and Yosemite so i'm sticking with 5.1.1 and waiting for apple to update and fix a lot of bugs..  You can report a bug to apple about this..

Answer (score 0):

Visit for more details: 

[iPhone Simulator Quarter or Top Left part of the screen[Fixed]](http://myblog.antonyraphel.in/2015/09/iphone-simulator-screen-content-shown-part-or-quarter-screen.html)

Watch the video from this link: [iPhone Simulator - Quarter of the screen [Fix]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWemT2NCJNw)

Step 1: “Force Quit” the iOS Simulator

Step 2: Open “Spotlight Search” and type “**Chameleon Wizard**” (if you installed Chameleon Bootloader)

Step 3: In that popup window, click on “**org.chameleon.Boot**”

Step 4: Uncheck **display_0, Graphics Mode**(Clear that Dropbox also)**, cpus=1, npci=0x3000, dart=0**. Below shows an image with checked items those mentioned here. Just uncheck it all.

[image: Uncheck what already checked]
Step 5: Restart your Mac and try.