# A part of tabbedPage is sheltered in IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

Just a simple project of maui,it use tabbar shell
------AppShell-----

```
<Shell
    x:Class="TABSample.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TABSample"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    <TabBar>
       
        <Tab Title="Test">
            <ShellContent Title="Test1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}"   />
            <ShellContent Title="Test2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage2}"  />
        </Tab>
       
    </TabBar>


</Shell>
```

-----NewPage1---------------

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TABSample.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

-----------Iphone 14 pro IOS 16.2------------------

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P2FY.png)

cannot see the label text

----------Android--------------------------
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDoRn.png)

A part of tabbedPage is sheltered in IOS, the reason is iOS Simulator? [Screen content is only shown in a part of screen in iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272125/screen-content-is-only-shown-in-a-part-of-screen-in-ios-simulator)

but ohter page is ok

Comment: Tryed it on real device and not showing , it is behind the tabs . For now you can use this until the problem is fixed .<StackLayout Padding="{x:OnPlatform iOS='0,40,0,0', Android='0'}" > You can report it on Github , i think here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I could reproduce your issue. Just as @Bas H mentioned, the control is behind the tabs. I also found the same issue in Github: [Contentpage is cut off in iOS #8778](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8778). You could follow it.

For a workaround, you could set the page padding

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Padding = new Thickness(0, 40, 0, 0);
}
```

or set like @Bas H suggested but i think use Margin is better:

```
<VerticalStackLayout Margin="{x:OnPlatform iOS='0,40,0,0', Android='0'}" >
```